# Jquery remove item from dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () { 

  $lstAccountType = $('select[id*="account_type"]');

  $lstAccountType.change(function () {
    $(this).remove('option[text="select one"]')
  });

});
```

I want to remove the first element in my dropdown list when it is clicked. Does anyone have any pointers in regards to this?

Comment: this one worked for me. Not the other ones ( $("#list[value='elementid']").remove());Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should just be able to use:

```
$lstAccountType.change(function () {
    $lstAccountType.find("option[value='"+$lstAccountType.val()+"']").remove();
});
```

I haven't tested this, but have a go and let me know if it is any good or not?

**EDIT**

If you only want to remove the first option each time you could try:

```
$lstAccountType.change(function () {
    if ($lstAccountType.find("option:first").attr("value") == $lstAccountType.val()) {  
        $lstAccountType.find("option[value='"+$lstAccountType.val()+"']").remove();
    }
});
```

It needs some tidying up, but hopefully that might help.

**EDIT**

If you want to remove the first option only once you could do:

```
var first_option_removed = false;
$lstAccountType.change(function () {
    if (!first_option_removed) {
        if ($lstAccountType.find("option:first").attr("value") == $lstAccountType.val()) {  
            $lstAccountType.find("option[value='"+$lstAccountType.val()+"']").remove();
            first_option_removed = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Having thought about it this will remove each option that is selected though, which I imagine is not what you are looking for. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).remove('option:first')
```

should do the trick, if you're sure you always want to remove the first.

edit:

```
$(this).remove('option:contains(select one)');
```

should do it on text.

Comment: I would like to remove based on text

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want something easier to read, remember that you probably want to bind `onFocus` since you want to **remove the first list-item as soon as the select is clicked**.

```
$('#mySelectId').bind('focus' function(){
   var listItems = $('#mySelect li');
   if(listItems.length > 0){
      $(listItems[0]).remove();
   }
});
```