# Javascript: Cocoon gem - Not allowing identical input fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, simple-form, cocoon-gem

I am using the Cocoon gem to add users to an asset. I currently have it set up so that the form does not go past the max number of users I am allowing on said asset (based off of profile type). I was wondering if there was a way that previously selected users would not show up, or be greyed out/unclickable, in the subsequent drop-down selections.

Any help is much appreciated, and if more clarification is needed it can be provided.

JavaScript:

```
$ ->
  check_to_hide_add_link = ->
    max_users = parseInt($("#asset_max_users").val(), 10)
    if $("#assets_users .nested-fields").length >= max_users
      $("#assets_users .links a").hide()
    else
      $("#assets_users .links a").show()

  $("#assets_users").bind "cocoon:after-insert", ->
    check_to_hide_add_link()

  $("#assets_users").bind "cocoon:after-remove", ->
    check_to_hide_add_link()

  check_to_hide_add_link()
```

Asset.show:

```
- if @asset.users.empty?
  = simple_form_for([@asset_profile, @asset]) do |f|
    f.input :max_users, as: :hidden
    #assets_users
      = f.simple_fields_for :assets_users do |assets_user|
        = render "assets_user_fields", f: assets_user
      .links
        = link_to_add_association "Add Another User", f, :assets_users
      = f.submit
```

_assets_user_fields:

```
.nested-fields
  = f.input :user_id, collection: @users.order(:last_name), :label => "User"
  = link_to_remove_association "Remove", f
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018318/jquery-remove-item-from-dropdownlist Does this help?(Note its likely you have to add and remove them dynamically from each dropdown whenever one of the field values is changed).

Comment: Yep, you will have to handle this using javascript, if you want the list to change based on selections made in the browser. Not really a specific cocoon problem. When somebody clicks open the dropdown, build the list by removing the selected items from the total set of items. The answer @MarceloRisoli posted should get you started. Ask a more specific question when you get stuck.